# Jquery slideshow 100% width

Tags: jquery

I've got a Jquery slideshow working great. However, the width of the slides is controlled by the Jquery code in the `<head>`, see example

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    var currentPosition = 0;
    var slideWidth = 720;
    var slides = $('.slide');
    var numberOfSlides = slides.length;
```

What I need to do is set the width to 100%, how can I do this? Everytime I use the % symbol the slideshow stops working?

Cheers,
Andy

Here's the full code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
var currentPosition = 0; var slideWidth = 720; var slides = $('.slide'); var    numberOfSlides = slides.length;
// Remove scrollbar in JS
$('#slidesContainer').css('overflow', 'hidden');
// Wrap all .slides with #slideInner div
slides
.wrapAll('<div id="slideInner"></div>')
// Float left to display horizontally, readjust .slides width
.css({
  'float' : 'left',
  'width' : slideWidth
});
// Set #slideInner width equal to total width of all slides
$('#slideInner').css('width', slideWidth * numberOfSlides);
// Insert controls in the DOM
$('#slideshow')
.prepend('<span class="control" id="leftControl">Clicking moves left</span>')
.append('<span class="control" id="rightControl">Clicking moves right</span>');
// Hide left arrow control on first load
manageControls(currentPosition);
// Create event listeners for .controls clicks
$('.control')
.bind('click', function(){
// Determine new position
currentPosition = ($(this).attr('id')=='rightControl') ? currentPosition+1 : currentPosition-1;
// Hide / show controls
manageControls(currentPosition);
// Move slideInner using margin-left
$('#slideInner').animate({
  'marginLeft' : slideWidth*(-currentPosition)
});
});
// manageControls: Hides and Shows controls depending on currentPosition
function manageControls(position){
// Hide left arrow if position is first slide
if(position==0){ $('#leftControl').hide() } else{ $('#leftControl').show() }
// Hide right arrow if position is last slide
if(position==numberOfSlides-1){ $('#rightControl').hide() } else{   $('#rightControl').show() }
}   
});
</script>
```

Comment: have you tried `"100%"` and not just `100%`?  Otherwise we really need to see more code and if possible a  demo site.

Comment: Make sure you use quotes if you specify width as a percent: `var slideWidth = "100%";`

Comment: Thanks for your speedy response but "100%" didn't work I'm afraid. I've edited the original question and added the full code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
var currentPosition = 0;
var slideWidth = getInt($("body").css("width"));
var slides = $('.slide');
var numberOfSlides = slides.length;

function getInt(num)
{
    if (isNaN(num)) {
        return num.replace(/[^-0-9]/g,"");
    } else {
        return num;
    }
}
</script>
```

While it's not a perfect solution, it will at least set the width to the page width at load time.  You'd have to create an event handler for the `resize` event on the body if you wanted to fix the `slideWidth` variable when the user resizes the browser window.

Comment: Glad I could help.  If you consider this your answer, could you mark it as such to help Googlers out?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var slideWidth = document.body.offsetWidth;
```